# WordPress Woocommerce 'view basket' link points to old website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have developed a WordPress webstore using Woocommerce which works fine on my dev server (e.g. dev.foo.com). However when I migrate the site to my live production webserver (e.g. livefoo.com) and point the live domain to the site the 'view basket' button which appears once you have added an item to your basket still links to the dev server (e.g. dev.foo.com/basket, instead of livefoo.com/basket). I have run a couple of search and replace plugins to update the mysql database to change any instances to the new domain but the problem still remains. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It would be strange but the URL isn't hardcoded into part of the template is it?

Comment: not that I can see. I've just discovered that it is only a problem if you add a product to basket from the category page. If you log in to the individual product page the 'view basket' link works fine. I guess it is either a hardcoded link in the html or the database.

Comment: Have you checked your templates? Are you filtering `woocommerce_get_cart_url`? The "cart" link is the permalink of a page ID so it shouldn't be hard-coded. And just for the heck of it, flush your permalinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help. I ran through and checked permalinks, database etc. I finally found some hard coded lines in a woo commerce template page called 'footer-woo.php' which I replaced and everything now is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you need to go to your wordpress setting and save your permalinks so it can be rewritten. if this does not solve the issue please export the database again and open it in wordpad and do a search for the link on your dev site to ensure that the database on the live server no longer has any of these links left in it. wordpad is very useful to use to check ur database file for these bad links. Good Luck